# What can I do, when the compare tool compares the wrong lines?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, git-diff, staging

I had the following code. (I added line numbers for clarification)

```
(1) if (foo1)
(2) {
(3)     some code 1
(4) }
```

I changed the if condition to `if (foo1 || bar1)`. I also added similar code above, what results in

```
(1) if (foo0 || bar0)
(2) {
(3)     some code 0
(4) }
(5) 
(6) if (foo1 || bar1)
(7) {
(8)     some code 1
(9) }
```

I use git. The Visual Studio compare tool now thinks that I replaced `if (foo1)` with `if (foo0 || bar0)` and that I added the rest, including `if (foo1 || bar1)`, as new code.

```
(1) if (foo1)           (1) if (foo0 || bar0)
(-)                     (2) {
(-)                     (3)     some code 0
(-)                     (4) }
(-)                     (5)
(-)                     (6) if (foo1 || bar1)
```

This is a problem, because I want to separate the changes into 2 commits. But I cannot stage only the change of the if condition, because the compare tool does not see, that it is a change. What could I do? Is it e. g. possible to manually link line 1 with line 6?

Comment: Change first `if` -> Commit -> Add second `if` -> Commit (?)

Comment: Good workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use patch commits:

1. Run `git commit --patch`, this will run an interactive commit
2. Tell git to split into smaller hunks (`s`)
3. Stage the first hunk (`y`) and don't stage the second (`n`)
4. Write a message for the first commit
5. Run `git add .` and `git commit` for the second commit

If you run `?` during the patch you can see what all the options do, like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP3Vy.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to link line 1 to 6.

I would suggest you separate them into two commits like the following:

1. Perform the change of: if (foo1 || bar1)
2. Git commit
3. Perform the change of: if (foo0 || bar0)
4. Git commit

Alternatively, instead of the first commit you can perform git add to stage it and this will give you the ability to compare too.